# How can I select all in a linq statement?

Tags: linq, select

Instead of selecting each item in both models, I would like to select all items from every model in the query without having to individually assign the values.

```
 var test = from x in y
               from z in x.week
               select new { Item = x.id, Week = z.weekDate };
```

I can select all in sql and hoped there is an easy way in Linq.

```
select * from x, y where x.id=y.id and x.id = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

```
var test = from x in y
               from z in x.week
               select new { x, z};
```

but you might want to do a join instead of two from clauses, otherwise you'll get a full outer join.

Comment: The select `from` references the variable from the first. This is a one-to-many query so two `from`s are correct.

Comment: OK, so then you don't need the second from clause at all. Just select x and then you can refer to x.week.whatever directly.

Comment: Check out the accepted answer from Fernando... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14a15314-0487-4f1c-a4ee-145e1cf6c384/linq-query-with-where-condition-on-parent-and-child-entity?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: That's not the same thing.

Comment: It also demonstrates that you can refer to child attributes directly without joining the child in the query

Comment: Yes, it does do that, but that's not what the query is trying to do.